# change CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag in django for mysql-python (MySQLdb)?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, mysql-python

I have a problem with MySQL 5.5 `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` rows effected mismatch cursor.rowcount in a normal Django project

According to [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html):

> For INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its current values. **If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag**, the affected-rows value is 1 (not 0) if an existing row is set to its current values.

So I tried in out, it seems that in mysql shell, repeating the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement will show

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

In mysql-python (import MySQLdb),

`cursor.rowcount` will always be 1 regardless of insert/update/nothing updated

I searched everywhere and can not find a way to change the `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag in Django. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found out how.

In django/db/backends/mysql/base.py there's

```
kwargs['client_flag'] = CLIENT.FOUND_ROWS
kwargs.update(settings_dict['OPTIONS'])
```

From the source code we could just change django project settings.py like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.',
        'NAME': '',                      
        'USER': '',                      
        'PASSWORD': '',                  
        'HOST': '', 
        'PORT': '',                      
        'OPTIONS': {
            'client_flag': 0
        }
    }
}
```